# How To Show A "Browser-Native" Dialog Box From A Web URL

Tags: javascript, html, browser

When a user requests my URL, how can I show a dialog box to ask for login credentials first before showing anything, like this:

- https://pasteboard.co/I9aeDzI.png
- https://pasteboard.co/I9af5i7.png

Seems to me these dialog boxes are in-built or native to the browser. Also, when a user clicks on Submit, is it like an ordinary  HTML tag?

It'll be good if someone can post links to relevant documentation on this feature, which I currently cannot seem to find with a simple Google search as I don't know what keywords appropriately describe it.

Like to learn more including:

1. How to get the webpage to show it ?
2. what happens behind the hood when someone clicks on `Submit` (eg. what HTTP request method it uses, which URL it will call) ?

Comment: you can style any dialog box to look like that with simple css

Comment: The first one is an HTTP authentication dialog. You’ll be able to find a lot of resources on it – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication for example – but it’s not a great authentication mechanism, really. What kind of resource are you wanting to protect with it? (I guess the second one is the same – never used Safari – but it looks kind of fake until you see the “Log in to …” in the address bar.)

Answer (score -1):

Those are made with pure CSS and JavaScript.

You can't find anything like that because they aren't native browser features.

Maybe you see many websites using the same dialog box because they use templates and libraries built for that purpouse.

Take a look at this

```js
var $btn = document.getElementById("submit");
var $form = document.getElementById("form")

function signIn() {
  if ($form.checkValidity()) {
    $btn.classList.add('pending');
    window.setTimeout(function(){ $btn.classList.add('granted'); }, 1500);
  }
}

$btn.addEventListener("click", signIn);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,900,900i|Monoton");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #68d8d6, #ffffff);
  color: #454749;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: Monoton, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

/**
 * Tiles
 */
.tile {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: .1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.75rem 1.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0.25rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 24rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tile .tile-header {
  background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dgmilxzy7/image/upload/c_scale,w_500,o_75,b_rgb:07beb8/v1506735375/CodePen/ViddenPixel.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 12rem;
}
.tile .tile-body {
  padding: 2rem;
}

/**
 * Forms
 */
.form-input {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.form-input > .material-icons {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  top: 1.2rem;
}
.form-input > .material-icons ~ input, .form-input > .material-icons ~ .label, .form-input > .material-icons ~ .underline {
  margin-left: 2.25rem;
  width: calc(100% - 2.25rem);
}
.form-input input {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 0;
  outline-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.form-input input ~ .label {
  color: #868e96;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  left: 0;
  transition: top .2s,font .2s;
  z-index: 1;
}
.form-input input ~ .underline {
  background-color: #bdc1c5;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.form-input input:hover ~ .underline, .form-input input:focus ~ .underline {
  background-color: #07beb8;
}
.form-input input:hover ~ .label, .form-input input:focus ~ .label {
  color: #07beb8;
}
.form-input input:focus ~ .underline {
  height: 2px;
}
.form-input input:focus ~ .label, .form-input input:valid ~ .label {
  top: 0;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
}
.form-input input:-webkit-autofill ~ .label {
  top: 0;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
}

/**
 * Buttons
 */
.btn {
  border-radius: .2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.btn, [role="button"], [type="button"] {
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-irenic {
  background-color: #07beb8;
  color: white;
}
.btn-irenic:hover, .btn-irenic:focus, .btn-irenic:active {
  background-color: #06a5a0;
}

.btn-serene {
  background-color: #3dccc7;
  color: white;
}
.btn-serene:hover, .btn-serene:focus, .btn-serene:active {
  background-color: #32beb9;
}

.btn-tranquil {
  background-color: #68d8d6;
  color: white;
}
.btn-tranquil:hover, .btn-tranquil:focus, .btn-tranquil:active {
  background-color: #54d3d0;
}

.btn-calm {
  background-color: #9ceaef;
  color: white;
}
.btn-calm:hover, .btn-calm:focus, .btn-calm:active {
  background-color: #86e5eb;
}

.btn-cool {
  background-color: #c4fff9;
  color: white;
}
.btn-cool:hover, .btn-cool:focus, .btn-cool:active {
  background-color: #abfff6;
}

.btn-ice {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: white;
}
.btn-ice:hover, .btn-ice:focus, .btn-ice:active {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.btn-base {
  background-color: #454749;
  color: white;
}
.btn-base:hover, .btn-base:focus, .btn-base:active {
  background-color: #393a3c;
}

/**
 * Utilities
 */
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

/**
 *
 */
.submit-container {
  position: relative;
}
.submit-container #submit {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: transform .1s ease-in, opacity .1s ease-in, border-radius .1s ease-in;
  right: -1px;
}
.submit-container #submit span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
}
.submit-container #submit.pending {
  transform: scale(0.55, 1.5);
  background-color: #07beb8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}
.submit-container #submit.pending span {
  opacity: 0;
}
.submit-container #submit.pending ~ .login-pending {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  z-index: 3;
}
.submit-container #submit.granted ~ .login-pending {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-9rem, -11rem) scale(18, 18);
  z-index: 3;
}
.submit-container #submit.granted ~ .login-pending .spinner {
  opacity: 0;
}
.submit-container #submit.granted ~ .login-pending .login-granted-content {
  opacity: 1;
}
.submit-container .login-pending {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background-color: #07beb8;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: 1rem;
  bottom: -0.5rem;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(0, 0) scale(0.5, 0.5);
  transition: transform .2s ease-in, scale .2s ease-in;
  z-index: 1;
}
.submit-container .login-pending .login-granted-content {
  background-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dgmilxzy7/image/upload/c_scale,w_700,o_25,b_rgb:07beb8/v1506735375/CodePen/ViddenPixel.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in .2s;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #ffffff;
}
.submit-container .login-pending .login-granted-content .material-icons {
  font-size: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1.25px;
}

.spinner {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.spinner .dot1, .spinner .dot2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #68d8d6;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: dot-bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: dot-bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.spinner .dot2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dot-bounce {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes dot-bounce {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
.label {
    display: inline;
    padding: .2em .6em .3em;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-radius: .25em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->


  <div class="tile">
  <div class="tile-header">
    <h2 style="color: white; opacity: .75; font-size: 4rem; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100%;">SIGN IN</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tile-body">
    <form id="form">
      <label class="form-input">
        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
        <input type="text" autofocus="true" required />
        <span class="label">Username</span>
        <span class="underline"></span>
      </label>
      
      <label class="form-input">
        <i class="material-icons">lock</i>
        <input type="password" required />
        <span class="label">Password</span>
        <div class="underline"></div>
      </label>
      
      <div class="submit-container clearfix" style="margin-top: 2rem;">          
        <div id="submit" role="button" type="button" class="btn btn-irenic float-right" tabindex="0">
          <span>SIGN IN</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="login-pending">
          <div class=spinner>
            <span class="dot1"></span>
            <span class="dot2"></span>
          </div>
          
          <div class="login-granted-content">
            <i class="material-icons">done</i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Completely wrong, sorry. You can even see it extending out of the page in the screenshot.

Comment: It's not a screenshot. Which browser are you using? In Google Chrome it works flawlessy

Comment: The screenshots in the question. You can see the prompt extending out of the page in the Chrome screenshot, because it’s part of the browser, not part of the page.

Comment: @Ry- You are right. However I am a Java programmer therefore I cannot C#